# Unable to delete the document from Lucene index

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm new to Lucene.net. I've been trying to delete a document from Lucene index file. But unfortunately I couldn't get it done.

Here is my code.

```
public void DeleteDocuments()
{
   Term term = new Term("id", id);
   Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_30);
   Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(filePath);
   IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
   writer.DeleteDocuments(term);
   writer.Optimize();
   writer.Commit();
   writer.Dispose();
}
```

Unable to delete the document from the index file. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Is there a write.lock file in the index directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the Analyzer you are using for the "id" field.

If your id includes letters, the StandardAnalyzer will index them in lower case. This would mean that the term you are creating might have a different value than was indexed "ABC" vs "abc".

Fo id type fields you should ensure that the field is created with no analysis.